# Saving a file to Sharepoint with R

Tags: r

Is it possible to save directly an R object to the company SharePoint from a local computer? I found how to import data into R from the Share point, but could not find how to work it to the other end. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone from IT department helped us to solve the issue. As I said we were able to import data from share point using the link to the folder. However the same link did not work when trying to save on SharePoint. To be able to do this the IT team gave us a slightly changed link. See below the type of link we used to upload and the one that was recommended and that works.

```
https://siteadress/foldername/subfolder/docname.rda
```

the one that works is

```
\\\\siteadress@SSL\\foldername\\subfolder\\docname.rda
```